# hide directory name and index.php from url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, drupal

Inside my **drupal** project **www.example.com** I have **codeigniter** project folder **example1**. 
I can access **codeigniter** project with Url like **www.example.com/example1/user/..**
How can I remove the folder name **example1** from **url**.
Pls suggest any solution

Thanks 
Ashish

Comment: You also want to run your drupal project?

Comment: my drupal project is running on www.example.com but the thing is that I have put the codeigniter project inside a folder name example1 and it is running with www.example.com/example1/user  i just want to remove the folder name example1 from url

Answer (score 0):

Please try with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /example1/$0 [PT,L] 
php_value post_max_size 2136746229
```